# XML Schema (XSD) to Entity Object Model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm new the **Entity Framework**. I was wondering if there is a way to transform an **XML Schema (XSD)** into an **Entity Object Model**, for the purpose of generating a Database according to it using the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it should be possible to use the XSD.exe in the [.NET Framework SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=71deb800-c591-4f97-a900-bea146e4fae1) to generate POCO-classes, and then use Entity Framework to generate the .edmx from those POCOs.

Comment: For me at least, if I go to Visual Studio 2013 in start menu and open the Visual Studio Command Prompt, I can run XSD.exe from there.

Comment: Sorry to res after 2 years, but I'm trying to do the same thing.
I've gotten classes from exd.exe, but I don't understand how you "Use Entity Framework to generate the .edmx from those POCOs". There doesn't seem to be any way add already created classes to a model.

Comment: I dont undestand too. How can I generate edmx from those POCOs?

Answer (score 0):

I am using xsd to class generator  http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/